# Where do (merely) differentiable functions stand in the $C^k$ differentiability class hierarchy?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Now $f$ is in $C^0$ iff it is continuous, $f$ is in $C^1$ iff its derivative is continuous, etc. Where would one classify a function "between" $C^0$ and $C^1$, ie. a function that's differentiable but its derivative is not continuous?

Comment: It could possibly be in a Holder $C^{0,\alpha} $ class but I think that would depend on the function. Try playing with the continuous extension of $x^a \sin(x^b)$ where (for this particular purpose) $a>1,b <0$, that is a source of a wealth of useful examples.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Yes, differentiable functions are continuous but not $C^1$, so that's "where" they are. But you seem to know this already. They do not have to be $C^{0,\alpha}$ for any $\alpha > 0$.

Comment: @Ian If you post that as an answer, I can accept it